# Is gcc's implementation of `std::random_device` correct?

Tags: c++, random-seed

The [gcc implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/random.cc) of `std::random_device` seems strange to me. Specifically, line 137:

```cpp
  random_device::result_type
  random_device::_M_getval()
  {
#if (defined __i386__ || defined __x86_64__) && defined _GLIBCXX_X86_RDRAND
    if (!_M_file)
      return __x86_rdrand();
#endif
```

Assume that all these quantities are defined. Then when I call the call operator on a `std::random_device` instance, I get the result from a `rdrand` instruction. But `rdrand` doesn't implement a random device; `rdrand` is a pseudorandom number generator, closer to (say) Mersenne twister than a physical source or randomness.

I would've expected a call to an `rdseed` buildin/intrinsic here, since `rdseed` queries a circuit which produces random numbers via [thermal noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand). This feels more like a "device" to me.

But I don't know much about random number generation; so is my thinking process about the implementation of `std::random_device` incorrect? Why?

Comment: `std::random_device` is even allowed to be deterministic (i.e. always produce the exact same sequence). Nevermind being required to be physically random.

Comment: `rdrand` isn't really like Mersenne twister. It's a cryptographically secure PRNG that is periodically reseeded from a hardware entropy source.

Answer (score 1):

## `std::random_device` is allowed to fall-back to a pseudorandom generator

> `std::random_device` may be implemented in terms of an implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to the implementation. In this case each `std::random_device` object may generate the same number sequence.
>
> —**`std::random_device`**, [C++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device)

I can't speak to GCC's decision to implement `random_device` in this manner in the situation where that macro evaluates to true, but given the `if(!_M_file)` check, my *guess* is that `_M_file` is a reference to what constitutes a potential source of entropy, and that in its absence, GCC will fallback to a regular pseudorandom device.

Comment: Of course, in this case, a non-deterministic source *is* in fact available. So a strictly legal reading of that sentence would indicate that the implementation is incorrect.

Comment: @user14717 Well, again: I'm not sure exactly what `if(!_M_file)` is doing. The negation of the object *implies* to me that it's checking for the absence of whatever `_M_file` is, and that if that did not return true, `_M_file` would be used for something; but I'm not sure.

Comment: From the linked github, it looks like `_M_file` should point to a file representing a random device. `random_device` would then attempt to read `sizeof(result_type)` bytes from that file. So it seems you are correct that the implementation is attempting to use a random source and falls back to `__x86_rdrand();`. Edit : It also seems like `random_device::entropy()` will return zero if there's a problem reading from that file.

Comment: @user14717 — a “strictly legal” reading of “may be implemented” allows that it also might not be implemented that way. I don’t know what language rules are applied by the quoted source, but in the standard, “may” means “is allowed to”. A requirement, on the other hand, uses “shall”.